# Chromecast and Charles Proxy - How to connect

Tags: debugging, proxy, chromecast, charles-proxy

I am trying to connect my Chromecast and monitor its traffic through Charles proxy but I have been unsuccessful so far. Can someone guide me on how to do the same. I tried setting up a wifi hotspot on my laptop and connecting my chromecast to it, but it did not help. Can someone please tell me how I could use Charles proxy with my chromecast.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmm yes, I think that will only work if you can specify a proxy server for the Chromecast to use. I don't believe you would have that kind of setting available to you in the Chromecast, but it may attempt to perform proxy autodiscovery when it joins the network, using WPAD. So you you may be able to specify your laptop as the proxy server for your network in your wifi router settings. If you can point that to Charles, then you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser console to look into Chromecast traffic. Your Chromecast device and your computer should be in the same wifi network. Open Chrome browser and enter address: `chrome://inspect`, it will open chrome dev tools. If your Chromecast device is connected and running you will see chromecast in `Devices` section, and `inspect` button. Click that button, and Chrome will open new window with Receiver page and console, where you can see all network requests in `Network section`.

Comment: I think this is not entirely correct. The page here states that you have to use a custom receiver app for this https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom router with DD-WRT for example and apply IP tables. See https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables_command